# How can I center the nav menu items using bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**My Navbar:**
[image]

**Problem**

How can I get the admin menu item to be in the middle rather than dropping to the left? I'm using a template I purchased from wrapbootstrap and cannot figure out why this is happening. I've tweaked a lot of CSS using the dev tools in firefox and no matter what I do, ADMIN hangs to the left.

**CSS:**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                                <div class="container-fluid">

                                    <!-- Toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                                    <div class="navbar-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Games</a>
                                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Results", "Index", "Results", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("League Table", "Index", "LeagueTable", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Schedule", "Index", "Schedule", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Players", "Index", "Players", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", "News", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Gallery", "Index", "Gallery", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { })</li>
                                            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                                            {
                                                <li class="dropdown">
                                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Admin</a>
                                                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Games", "Index", "Games", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Game Types", "Index", "GameTypes", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", "News", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Players", "Index", "Players", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Seasons", "Index", "Seasons", new { area = "Admin" }, new { })</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            }
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before. I reduced the font-size.

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
   /*reduce font-size here*/
}
```

I reduced the padding between the navbar elements.

```
.navbar-nav > li{
  padding-left:30px;/*reduce*/
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

You can also change the margins. It works too:

```
.navbar-nav > li{
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

Another way to go about it is using the media queries: check which screen-size has the admin dropping down and maybe turn one or two elements into a dropdown at that screen-size: for example have gallery and contacts into a dropdown called More. So when the user clicks it, he will have the option to choose between the two.

Comment: I appreciate that this is a work around and you're quite right, I could reduce the font size or reduce the padding. I just wonder how would I actually achieve the original question?

Comment: @paulpitchford i dont think so because let's think about it this way: if you block the navbar from moving to the next line then it wouldn't fit in your screen hence creating a horizontal scrollbar which will be bad for user experience and will means your website is not completely responsive

Comment: Point taken. Back to the drawing board. Thanks for the input.